# Appending sum of last two integers of a list to that same list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Edit: I should add that the focus for this problem is on the use of 'side effects' in a function.

I am submitting my code on my computing course on Coursera. I think I must be missing something super obvious. When I submit my code I get the following error:

---

**#TEST 5#**
append_fibonacci(args) returned None
** ERROR ** side effect from: [-5, 8, 1] to: [-5, 8, 1]
* EXPECTED: * [-5, 8, 3]
inputs:

outputs:

---

I mostly just don't understand what the feedback is telling me. I'm a bit of a newbie, having just started Python this month. Thank you for your help!

The following is my code:

```
def append_fibonacci(integer_list):
  # Modify the argument list of integers by
  # appending a new integer that is the sum
  # of the last two integers in the list.
  # If the list has fewer than two elements
  # add the int object 1 to the list.

  if len(integer_list) > 2:
    sum_last_two = ((integer_list[-1]) + (integer_list[-2]))
    integer_list.append(sum_last_two)
  else:
    integer_list.append(1)

def main():
  # Call the append_fibonacci function on this
  # list: [3, 5, 8] and output the result object

  number_list = [3, 5, 8]
  append_fibonacci(number_list)
  print(number_list)

main()
```

Comment: You have to return the list at the end of the function `append_fibonacci`.

Comment: Your function not return nothig.

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Comment: I ran the exact code snippet and got the following output which is correct - `[3, 5, 8, 13]` . The word **TEST** in your post suggests that the solution is failing for some other input. Please diagnose what inputs are triggering that. Also, @RemyJ - there is no issue with the not returning the list - in Python, mutable objects are passed as reference. So the list passed as a parameter is modified itself.

Comment: @RemyJ why? Conventionally, functions that modify their arguments simply return `None`. This isn't a requirement, and is really a design choice up to you, but there's no reason this would *require* it.

Comment: Thanks for point out my misunderstanding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you got is saying that the updated list should be `[-5, 8, 3]` but you're setting it to `[-5, 8, 1]`

This is because your function doesn't work correctly if the list has *exactly* 2 elements. It should add the two elements and append the sum (`-5 + 8 = 3`), but it will instead just append `1`.

```
if len(integer_list) > 2:
```

should be:

```
if len(integer_list) >= 2:
```